# hamletFile, luciusFile, juliusFile variables not in scope

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-stack, template-haskell

I'm building a simple application using Yesod and I'm having a hard time bringing in external files. Here is my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}
import           Yesod

data GomokuServer = GomokuServer

mkYesod "GomokuServer" [parseRoutes|
/ HomeR GET
|]

instance Yesod GomokuServer

getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = defaultLayout $ do 
        $(hamletFile "./src/templates/home.hamlet")
        $(luciusFile "./src/templates/home.lucius")

main :: IO ()
main = warp 3000 GomokuServer
```

It works great when I use quasiquotes, or if I replace `hamletFile` with `whamletFile`, but otherwise it won't compile because it can't find `hamletFile` or `luciusFile`. I'm using Yesod version 1.4 and I thought those methods where imported with the core Yesod package. Are they not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just use `whamletFile`? Most of the time you want a widget.

It seems `hamletFile` is not re-exported.

```
λ import Yesod
λ :t hamletFile

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • Variable not in scope: hamletFile
    • Perhaps you meant ‘whamletFile’ (imported from Yesod)
```

If you really need it, you could bring it in from [Text.Hamlet](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.9/shakespeare-2.0.14/Text-Hamlet.html#v:hamletFile).

FWIW the [Yesod scaffolding](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod-scaffold) defines a function

```
widgetFile :: String -> Q Exp
widgetFile = (if appReloadTemplates compileTimeAppSettings
                then widgetFileReload
                else widgetFileNoReload)
              widgetFileSettings
```

And then I just use this everywhere like `$(Settings.widgetFile "homepage")` which by default brings in the hamlet, lucius, and cassius files for "homepage". You can see more info at [Overriding-widgetFile on the Yesod wiki](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Overriding-widgetFile)

Comment: Can I use `whamletFile` to import external `.lucius` files? I was under the impression it would only work with `.hamlet` files.  I ended up importing using Text.Hamlet.

Comment: You cannot use `whamletFile` to import lucius files, but you can use the `widgetFile` function which will import all 3 hamlet, lucius, and cassius files.

Comment: But `widgetFile` is not included in the core yesod library, right? I would have to add yesod-scaffold to my dependency list, which seems like an overkill, considering that’s the only function I’ll use.

Comment: The yesod-scaffold repo is used by `stack new` to generate new project templates. I don't think you can even include it as a dependency with cabal/stack. You could just copy the function into your project though: https://github.com/bitemyapp/ghcjs-starter-project/blob/master/backend/Settings.hs#L85-L105